# How to add array data to the firestore

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a firestore document where 'comments' is a array i need to add data of string to the existing array

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
                  .collection('products')
                  .doc('${widget.product.id}')
                  .update({"comments": FieldValue.arrayUnion(_currentName});
```

Comment: Please edit the question explain what isn't working the way you expect with the code you've written.  Be specific.  I suggest reading: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I do it:

```
Firestore.instance
    .collection('products')
    .document('${widget.product.id}')
    .updateData({"comments": FieldValue.arrayUnion([_currentName])});
```

Comment: I did spend quite some time myself finding out the first time. The documentation on this is very poor. Glad it helped! Don't forget to upvote and validate the answer if you think it's the right one :)